# My login script is being hacked

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

My login script is being hacked (the hacking can bypass the login and get into the members section).

Here is my login:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post"> 
<table width="450px"><tr><td>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{   

$user= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$user22 = strip_tags($user);
$pass= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$pass2 = strip_tags($pass);
$pass1 = md5($pass2);

$mod = 1 ;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$user22."' AND password = '".$pass1."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$battle_get = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if ( $battle_get['mod'] == 1 ) {
                $month = time() + 3600*24*30;
                $hour = time() + 3600*1*1;
                $LastLogin = date('l, M d, Y H:i:s');
                $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username'];
                setcookie("save_user", stripslashes(htmlentities($user22)), $hour); 
                setcookie("save_pass", stripslashes(htmlentities($user22)), $month);
                $username = stripslashes(htmlentities($user22));
                $result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET LastLogin = '$LastLogin' WHERE username='$username'");
                header("location: home.php"); 
}

}
?></td></tr></table>
<ul><li class="topper" style="width:410px;"></li>
<table>
<tr><td>Username</td><td><input type="text" name="username" id="textfield"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="password" name="password" id="textfield"></td></tr>
</table><li class="bottomer" style="width:410px;"></li></ul>
<table><tr><td><input type="submit" name="login" value="login" id="button"></td></tr></table>
</form>
```

And then in my config file i have this code which stops the user from changing IP each login etc.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['last_ip']) == false){
    $_SESSION['last_ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    if ($_SESSION['last_ip'] !== $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']){

    session_unset();
    session_destroy();

    }

if(empty($_SESSION['user'])){
         echo"Please login into the rpg first" ;
         die;
}
```

I inculde the config file (the code above) on every page the if is empty stops the users from viewing in side the site...  The hacker is telling me he is using sql to get in.....

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would recommend to read [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: How do you know the password wasn't brute-forced? Are you sure they're hacking the script, or did they just guess the proper username and password.

Comment: There is a ton of SQL Injection discussions going on with people not protecting them properly :/

Comment: Well they told me they go in though sql

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 2):

He is using SQL injection. He is changing the $_POST of 'username' to something like

```
"username; OR 1=1"
```

and because 1=1 is "true", it lets him in. You are not protected from the ";"

Theres lots of information around about SQL injection and how to protect yourself.

Comment: How would i fix this ???

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: So instead of using $pass1  i use :pass1   ??

Comment: actually - since you are hashing the password - he must be using the Username field (i've edited my answer). So yes, you need to run $user through the prepared statement function to render it safe

Comment: prepared statement function ??

Comment: i escape the username and strip it... So what else do i need to do with it ?

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$user22."' AND password = '".$pass1."'";
```

is dangerous (SQL injection), I recommend you to use prepared statements with `PdoMySQL`.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Sql Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), and view examples here:
http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

Your specific sql looks like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$user22."' AND password = '".$pass1."'";
```

This is ripe for sql injection.

Have a look at some of the following:

- http://www.learnphponline.com/security/sql-injection-prevention-mysql-php
- http://www.tech-evangelist.com/2007/11/05/preventing-sql-injection-attack/
- http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/ProPHPSecurity_excerpt.php3
- http://25yearsofprogramming.com/blog/2011/20110205.htm

These were just a few of the top links when searching for how to prevent sql injection attacks in php.

Comment: $user is obtained from mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
so it should already be escaped. However is it possible that striptags is causing somethign that's escaped to be unescaped. Although I doubt it.

Comment: How would i change that ?? Because everything is escaped

Answer (score 0):

Read a little about [SQL injection here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: i thought escape every string and striping each virable would make me safe enough ??

Answer (score 0):

please take a look to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string).

He explain about sql injection and `mysql_real_escape_string();`